# How to compare only year and month in date field in php mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date field which has data like `2017-01-10`, `2017-02-12`, `2017-05-14` and so on. Here, how do I check if any of the field has October, 2017 date in it (ignoring the day) ?

Comment: I don't think the stated duplicate was really a duplicate.  For one thing, the answers focused on the current date, but this is for an arbitrary date.  Also, the accepted answer is not the best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you use an inequality like this:

```
where datefield >= '2017-10-01' and datefield < '2017-11-01'
```

This approach has two advantages:

- The query optimizer can use an available index, if appropriate.
- The same logic works if `datefield` has a time component.

If you do something like this:

```
where year(datefield) = 2017 and month(datefield) = 10
```

Then MySQL will not use an index.  (The same is true of `yearmonth()` and formatting the column.)